# Swift get max key from and sort

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have `var dataDictionary = [[String:Any]]()` and data inside :

```
[["quant": 10, "name": "..."], 
["quant": 20, "name": "..."], 
["quant": 25, "name": "..."],
["quant": 27, "name": "..."],
["quant": 30, "name": "..."],
["quant": 30, "name": "..."],
["quant": 20, "name": "..."],
["quant": 40, "name": "..."],
["quant": 15, "name": "..."],
...]
```

I want to get max from all "quant" and then create func to make a selection int to maxKey and print 
For example need get from 30 to maxKey and get :

```
[["quant": 30, "name": "..."],
["quant": 30, "name": "..."],
["quant": 40, "name": "..."]]
```

Im try to get max like this:

```
let maxVal = dataDictionary.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
```

but have error

> Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'value'

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary

Comment: Your *dictionary* is an array. You cannot use `value` with dot notation, you have to use key subscripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 dataDictionary.sort { (v1, v2) -> Bool in
  return v1["quant"] as? Int ?? 0 <  v2["quant"] as? Int ?? 0
}
let min = 30
let max = dataDictionary.last!["quant"] as? Int ?? min
let filtered = dataDictionary.filter({(dict) in
  let valueToCompare = dict["quant"] as! Int
  return valueToCompare >= min && valueToCompare <= max
})
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access `"quant"` value through subscription:

```
var dataDictionary = [[String:Any]]()
let maxVal = dataDictionary.max { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    let leftValue = lhs["quant"] as? Int ?? 0
    let rightValue = rhs["quant"] as? Int ?? 0
    return leftValue < rightValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `max` on the `array` so You have to access quant from `keyValue pair` like this way:

```
    dataDictionary.max { (a, b) -> Bool in
        return a["quant"] as! Int > b["quant"] as! Int
        //Or with optional
        return a["quant"] as? Int ?? 0 > b["quant"] as? Int ?? 0

     }
```

OtherWise when you are doing it on `[String: Any]` then you can do like as same as you are doing

```
let greatestDict = dataDictionary.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
print(greatestDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tried mechanism,

```
let maxVal = dataDictionary.max { a, b in a.value < b.value }
```

a, b are dictionaries of type `[String: Any]` which do not have `.values` properties. So, to find max quant dictionary, you should use:

```
let maxVal = dataDictionary.max { a, b in (a["quant"] as! Int) < (b["quant"] as! Int) }
```

---

If you wished to get all the dictionaries having quant more than or equal to specific value, you have to use:

```
let quantLimit: Int = 30
let maxValFrom30 = dataDictionary.filter({ ($0["quant"] as! Int) >= quantLimit })
```